# Bi-directional relationship in nhibernate 4.0

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a code that was working perfectly on NHibernate 3.1, but when it is not working on NHibernate 4.0

So, this is the class relations

```
public class Employee : BaseEntity
{
    ...
    public Department Dept { get; set; }
}

public class Department : BaseEntity
{
    ...
    public IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

and for the mapping we have this

```
DepartmentMap : ClassMap<Department>
{
     Table("....");
     HasMany(x => x.Employees).KeyColumn("DeptId").Not.KeyNullable();
}


EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
     Reference(x => x.Dept).Column("DeptId");
}
```

and when I am adding an employee like that

```
var dept = session.Load<Department>(deptId);
newEmployee.Dept = dept;
session.Save(newEmployee);
```

But it is throwing an error:

> NHibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null
>   or transient value

I read that I have to add the relation in two ways, so I modified it to this

```
var dept = session.Load<Department>(deptId);
newEmployee.Dept = dept;
dept.Employees.Add(newEmployee);
session.Save(newEmployee);
```

But now I have this error :

> NHibernate.PropertyValueException: Error dehydrating property value
>   for... System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Invalid index 7 for this
>   SqlParameterCollection with Count=7.

So, I want to know how to fix it and where I can read about the changes in NHibernate about this with bi-direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix for the problem:
The fix for the problem is to add Inverse to the mapping of the parent file.
So, the mapping for Department will be:

```
DepartmentMap : ClassMap<Department>
{
     Table("....");
     HasMany(x => x.Employees).KeyColumn("DeptId").Inverse().Not.KeyNullable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### First issue - bi-directional mapping

We should always assign both sides of relation. Well, *always?!?* This is the perferred and good practice.

**But** in case, that we want to use **`.Load()`** to retrieve `parent`(Department) - we should **not** need assign `parent.Chidren.Add()`.

The `Load()` is smart way how to get "fake" (proxy) instance, represented just by ID of that entity *(engough to create proper INSERT statement)*

So, in this case we should avoid `dept.Employees.Add(newEmployee);` - we do not need to load Department at all

```
// existing parent - but NHibernate just creates a proxy with expected ID
var dept = session.Load<Department>(deptId);
// child Employee is provided with parent reference - it is enough
newEmployee.Dept = dept;
// this will not help, just will execute SELECT - no benefit
// dept.Employees.Add(newEmployee);
// save and it should work
session.Save(newEmployee);
```

#### Second (real) issue - double mapping

While it is not visible in the question code snippets, I would bet, that Employee in fact has this def and mapping

```
public class Employee : BaseEntity
{
    ...
    // reference
    public virtual Department Dept { get; set; }
    // reference_ID also mapped as integer
    public virtual int? DeptId { get; set; }
}

EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
     Reference(x => x.Dept).Column("DeptId");
     Map(x => x.DeptId)
         // with .Not.Nullable() by code or convention
         ; 
}
```

So - we have two properties in C# which belongs to one SQL Column. I would say, it is absolutely ok, but we have to be sure that we adjust that a bit. The integer should be nullable and MUST be readonly

```
EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
     Reference(x => x.Dept).Column("DeptId");
     Map(x => x.DeptId)
        .Nullable()
        .Insert(false)
        .Update(false); // as far as I rememeber syntax to replicate
      // <property name="DeptId" insert="false" update="false" not-null="false />
}
```

So what happened? what are both exceptions experienced aboout?

> NHibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value

the above issue means NHibernate expected property DeptId to be also provided

> NHibernate.PropertyValueException: Error dehydrating property value for... System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Invalid index 7 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=7.

this kind of issue is usually about doubled mapping - two properties to ONE column. Most often becuase of Reference and reference id being mapped to one column...

Even if the issue is not directly with **`int? DeptId`** - I hope that this give you enough information to reveal the real culprit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It gives me some info about what is going on. but that was not the problem.
I didn't have double column mapping and i didn't have that int? DeptId.
My problem was fixed by adding Inverse keyword.
Which I read that i was supposed to be there, but somehow in 3.1 was forgiving , but in 4.0 it errors out

Comment: Just a note: none of the exceptions you've experienced is related to inverse mapping. And in fact, inverse mapping (on Department side) is not anyhow related to scenario when you save Employee with `many-to-one` reference to such Department. My explanation is really related to issues you've mentioned in the query. But I am glad that youv've found the way...Enjoy NHibernate